# Find the solutions of equation $\{x\} + \{2x\} + \{3x\} + \{4x\}=3, x\in [0, 2017]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the solutions of equation $\{x\} + \{2x\} + \{3x\} + \{4x\}=3, x\in [0,
>  2017]$.

---

It is clear that the equation cannot have irrational solutions (it follows from $\{x\}=x- \lfloor {x} \rfloor$).

Also, if $x$ is solution then $x+n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is also solution.

I have found a solution in the required interval $[0,2017], x=\frac 9 {10}$ therefore $x=\frac 9 {10} + n, n \in \mathbb{N}, n\le 2016$ are also solutions.

The question is: how can I prove these are all possible solutions?

Comment: Because $\{x\}+\{2x\}+\{3x\}+\{4x\}-\{10x\}$ is an integer you can deduce that $10x$ must be an integer. Then only a finite search in the set $\{x=k/10\mid k=0,1,\ldots,9\}$ remains.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why $\{x\}+\{2x\}+\{3x\}+\{4x\}-\{10x\}$ is an integer?

Comment: $\{nx\}-n\{x\}$ is an integer for all reals $x$ and all integers $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanding my comments to an answer with a different approach)

**Fact.** For all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ the difference 
$n\{x\}-\{nx\}$ is an integer.

**Proof.**
If $x=m+\{x\}$ where $m\in\Bbb{Z}$, then we have
$$
nx=nm+n\{x\}.
$$
On the other hand $nx=\ell+\{nx\}$ for some integer $\ell$. Therefore
$$
n\{x\}-\{nx\}=(nx-nm)-(nx-\ell)=\ell-nm\in\Bbb{Z}.
$$
QED.

Let us first look for numbers $x$ such that $\{x\}+\{2x\}+\{3x\}+\{4x\}$ is an integer. Assume this is the case. By the above fact
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\{10x\}-\{x\}-\{2x\}-\{3x\}-\{4x\}\\
=&\bigg(\{10x\}-\{x\}-\{2x\}-\{3x\}-\{4x\}\bigg)+(-10+1+2+3+4)\{x\}\\
=&(\{10x\}-10\{x\})+(\{x\}-\{x\})+(2\{x\}-\{2x\})+(3\{x\}-\{3x\})+(4\{x\}-\{4x\})
\end{aligned}
$$
is always an integer. So if $\{x\}+\{2x\}+\{3x\}+\{4x\}$ is an integer we can conclude that $\{10x\}$ must also be an integer as a sum of two integers.

This means that if $x$ is a solution of your equation, then the number $10x$ must be an integer. Together with your observations this implies that you only need to check the choices
$x=0,1/10,2/10,\ldots,9/10$. The conclusion is that $x=9/10$ is the only solution in the range $[0,1)$.

Comment: I think I have a quicker way to show that $10x$ is an integer.  Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just find the solution in $(0,1)$,
Consider an $x$ belonging to $(0,1)$

If $ \{ x \}<.25$

Clearly it is not possible as then $ \{ x \}+ \{ 2x \}<1$ hence the sum cannot be $3$

Now if it's between $ 0.25\leq\{ x \}<.5$ then also it's not possible as 
either $ \{ 3x \}$ or $ \{ 4x \}<0.5$  hence by adding we get that the sum is less than $3$

Now if $ 0.5\leq\{ x \}<.75$ then also we will have a contradiction(Do it similarly $ \{ x \}<0.75$ so either $ \{ 3x \}$ or $ \{ 4x \}<0.75$ and $ \{ 2x \}<0.5$, we can get a contradiction by adding all)

So we have $ \{ x \}\geq0.75$
So $ \{ 2x \}=2x-1$
$ \{ 3x \}=3x-2$
$ \{ 4x \}=4x-3$

So $x+2x-1+3x-2+4x-3=3$
so $x=9/10$

Comment: Also $\{ x \}$ is less than 0.5 ,not just $\{ 3x \}$ or $\{4 x \}$

Comment: @Eugen Covaci I think you are wrong and his solution is correct. In case you mention first two summand sum to number $< 1$ and third and fourth by definition  $< 1$

Comment: @Hedgehog I didn't say it's incorrect, just poorly explained.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{u\}=u-\text{an integer}$ for any $u$, we have

$$\{x\}+\{2x\}+\{3x\}+\{4x\}=10x-k$$

for some integer $k$.  Therfore, if $\{x\}+\{2x\}+\{3x\}+\{4x\}=3$, we must have

$$x={k+3\over10}$$

for some $k$.  If we restrict $x$ to the interval $(0,1)$, then the two displayed equations imply $0\le k\le6$, which at worst leaves $7$ numbers to check.  There might be some slick way to narrow things down further, but I don't see one offhand.

Comment: Looks good to me. And, indeed, a bit quicker than my approach. My excuse is that my answer became longer than necessary because I wanted to fully explain my comments under the OP. :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks, yes, your approach is actually quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

since $x+n $ is a solution if $x $ is,
you just need to find solutions in $[0,1) $.
consider the cases

1. $0 <x<\frac 14$
2. $\frac 14 \leq x <\frac 13$
3. $\frac 13 \leq x <\frac 12$
4. $\frac 12\leq x <1$

For example, in $(0,\frac 14) $,
the equation becomes
$$10x=3$$.

$\frac{3}{10}\notin (0,\frac 14) $
there is no solution in $ [0,\frac 14) $.
...

Comment: I knew it, but how do I prove $x= \frac {9}{10}$ is the only solution in $[0,1)$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci You can do it now.

Comment: You may want to divide the case $1/2 \le x < 1$ into three subcases as well.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What are these three cases.

Comment: Since $\operatorname{LCM}(1,2,3,4)=12$ the behavior of the fractional part function can change at each $\frac 1{12}$.  I would consider what happens when $x$ is in each of these intervals.

Comment: $[1/2, 2/3)$, $[2/3, 3/4)$, $[3/4, 1)$.